# Actuator - status only information if security is disabled

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I want configure actuator in a way that:

Security configuration is disabled:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

And only available information is status:

```
"status" : "UP",
```

But after disabling security I get full complet of reduntant for me information.
I tried to disable health properties but after disabling all I ended with:

```
"status" : "UP", "application", "UP"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to do it.
First I create own HealthEndpoint where I cut down information other than status:

```
public class StatusOnlyHealthEndpoint extends HealthEndpoint {

public StatusOnlyHealthEndpoint(final Map<String, HealthIndicator> healthIndicators) {
    super(new OrderedHealthAggregator(), healthIndicators);
}

@Override
public Health invoke() {
    Health health = super.invoke();
    return Health.status(health.getStatus())
                 .build();
}}
```

Then I just override HealthEndpoint Bean with use of recent created Bean - thanks to that I can configure which indicators influence status from properties:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationHealth extends EndpointAutoConfiguration {

public ApplicationHealth(final ObjectProvider<HealthAggregator> healthAggregator,
                         final ObjectProvider<Map<String, HealthIndicator>> healthIndicators,
                         final ObjectProvider<List<InfoContributor>> infoContributors,
                         final ObjectProvider<Collection<PublicMetrics>> publicMetrics,
                         final ObjectProvider<TraceRepository> traceRepository) {
    super(healthAggregator, healthIndicators, infoContributors, publicMetrics, traceRepository);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint() {
    return new StatusOnlyHealthEndpoint(super.healthEndpoint());
}}
```